# Closing android application in command line

Tags: android

Is there any command i can use to close an application in adb shell, i can start my application using "am start" command in shell, But After searching exhaustively in google, i could not find an answer, for closing my application in the same way.

I want it to also work in non-rooted devices.

Comment: I just thought a way which could work in this case,
 1. OnPause exit the application 
2. send am start command with "--activity-previous-is-top" , could work in non-rooted device.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a broadcast intent. In your activity, register a broadcast receiver for a custom intent, for example `foo.bar.intent.action.SHUTDOWN`:

```
BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context ctx, Intent intent) {
        finish();
    }
};

registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter("foo.bar.intent.action.SHUTDOWN"));
```

And then, in order to exit the activity from the command line, send the broadcast Intent with `am`:

```
$ adb shell "am broadcast -a foo.bar.intent.action.SHUTDOWN"
```

Comment: Thanks, i think this will perfectly for me.

Comment: @sandroid Then mark this answer as the right answer. This way this question will get marked answered and olivierg gets the points for the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

Developer can kill application on emulator but not on real device unless it's rooted. If you want to kill app on emulator than go to dab shell and than,

```
su 
ps
**list will appear, for all processes** 
kill <Process ID here>
```